# How do I automate my Corel Draw Laser tasks using python?

Tags: python, automation, coreldraw

The mouse is directed to the icon but does not click
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65cr1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvolQ.png)

My script:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard


def click_on_screen():
    pyautogui.doubleClick(x=1685, y=13)
    


keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+a', click_on_screen)

keyboard.wait()
```

I want to click the icon to automate my tasks